# Assume $\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ are two-connected domain, if$f:\Omega_1\rightarrow\Omega_2$ is holomorphic cover mapping.

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ are two-connected domain. Suppose that  $f:\Omega_1\rightarrow\Omega_2$ is a holomorphic cover mapping. We want to show that $f$ is a finitely-sheeted covering mapping.

My idea: I can use some conclusion in algebraic topology such as $p_\pi(\pi_1(E,e))\rightarrow\pi_1(B,b)$ is monohomomorphism, if  $[\pi_1(B,b):H_e]$ is finite, the question is proved, here $H_e=p_\pi(\pi_1(E,e))$. But I do not know whether there are some gaps.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Each nontrivial subgroup of ${\mathbb Z}$ has finite index in it.

Comment: Are $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ connected domains? Or are $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ two-connected, i.e., their boundary consists of two connected components?